# If you have 2 linearly dependent vectors, is it possible to define any random vector on a 2d plane?

Tags: vector-spaces

If you have 2 linearly dependent vectors, is it possible to define any random vector on a 2d Cartesian plane? And no, this is not a homework question. Something that just struck my mind

EDIT: Sorry! i mean linearly **dependent**

Comment: *point*? I take it you mean vector. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, if you have two linearly independent vectors, they necessarily span the entire space (since $\dim\mathbb{R}^2=2$). It follows that every vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is expressible as a linear combination of those two.

Comment: @oldrinb oops sorry. I meant linearly **dependent** vectors. will change asap!

Comment: and yes i mean, any vector, not any point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- the answer is clearly *no*. If the two vectors are dependent, it follows that they are equal up to multiplication by a scalar. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, you can visualize this as them being *collinear*, either parallel or antiparallel. They therefore only span a 1-dimensional subspace (a line through the origin) which is clearly not the whole space...

Comment: exactly my though, thanks was just making sure!

Comment: you are correct then!

Answer (score 1):

No.

The [dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension#Dimension_of_a_vector_space) of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $2$.

If two vectors are linearly dependent then they span a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is of degree $\leq 1$ hence not all of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: yep! good answer.